# Execute updates as separate jobs / processes in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm working with a script as a stored procedure Google Bigquery which has multiple separate (20+) updates on the same table. An example update:

```
UPDATE
    mytable to_update
SET to_update.myfield = to_update.myfield + 20
FROM mytable
  INNER JOIN second_table 
  ON second_table.id = first_table.id
WHERE some_rules are TRUE
  AND to_update.id = mytable.id;
```

When running a script as a whole or calling the stored procedure I'm hitting BigQuery's update quota for the day and table. However, when I'm executing all the updates **separately** after each other (run selected option in the browser client) it works well.

**My question is** how can I automatically execute all the updates after each other the same way as manually running one-by-one (separately).

I tried separate `BEGIN - END` pairs and the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATELY` command but those did not work as part of a stored procedure or when ran in one command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#standard_tables), your error regarding reaching the *BigQuery's update quota per day* may be caused by one of the following:

1. *You are limited to 1,500 operations per table per day whether the operation appends data to a table or truncates a table.*

You need to have executed more than 1500 operations in a single table, the operation . In your case, each update statement counts as 1 towards the 1500 limit. Therefore, you did not reach this quota.

2. *Maximum rate of table metadata update operations — 5 operations every 10 seconds per table*

In this case, if you launch more than 5 operations within a 10 seconds window, your job will fail. For this reason,you get an error when executing all together but you are able to execute each of your update functions individually. Thus, this is the quote you are breaching.

There is a workaround by introducing delays between your [UPDATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_statement) statements within your procedure. Below I will share the sample data I have used and the steps I took in order to perform 25 updates in my sample data.

**First**, I created **two** tables with the following sample data,

```
name    age
Ralph   52
Leo 27
Alex    41
Mary    62
```

Second, I used the following code in between each 5 **UPDATES**,

```
#In the beginning of the code
DECLARE start_ts TIMESTAMP;

#code/UPDATES

#delay of 10 seconds
SET start_ts = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
WHILE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() < TIMESTAMP_ADD(start_ts, INTERVAL 10 SECOND) 
DO 
END WHILE;
```

Third, I created a **STORED PROCEDURE** to wrap around 25 updates to the same table, grouped in groups of 5 and with the above *delay code* in between. So it looks as below,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myDataset.multiple_updates()
BEGIN

DECLARE start_ts TIMESTAMP;

UPDATE dataset.table1 a
SET a.age = a.age + 1
from dataset.table1 t1 left join dataset.table2 t2 on t1.name = t2.name
WHERE a.name = t2.name;

UPDATE dataset.table1 a
SET a.age = a.age + 1
from dataset.table1 t1 left join dataset.table2 t2 on t1.name = t2.name
WHERE a.name = t2.name;

UPDATE dataset.table1 a
SET a.age = a.age + 1
from dataset.table1 t1 left join dataset.table2 t2 on t1.name = t2.name
WHERE a.name = t2.name;

UPDATE dataset.table1 a
SET a.age = a.age + 1
from dataset.table1 t1 left join dataset.table2 t2 on t1.name = t2.name
WHERE a.name = t2.name;

UPDATE dataset.table1 a
SET a.age = a.age + 1
from dataset.table1 t1 left join dataset.table2 t2 on t1.name = t2.name
WHERE a.name = t2.name;

SET start_ts = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
WHILE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() < TIMESTAMP_ADD(start_ts, INTERVAL 10 SECOND) 
DO 
END WHILE;

#I repeated the same above group 5 more times
#...

END;
```

Then you press `Run` and create your procedure. Now, you can call it and all the 25 updated will execute smoothly. You can call your procedure as follows,

```
 CALL `project_id.dataset.multiple_updates`();
```

Additionally, you can check the query execution details in order to confirm all the which were executed. Finally, I must point that I got the same error when running all the UPDATE above without the *delay function*.

*Note:  The example above is just a demonstration, that is the reason why I used the same update throughout the whole procedure.*

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about the maximum rate of table metadata update operations limit. This will resolve the problem, even if I don't like adding delays to the code just to meet a rate limit... still, it works and the code won't be that slow, even with the delay. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can try a Python scripting option:

1. Create script files having UPDATE statement and name them `update_script_1..N` (change to any other pattern you like)
2. Run the below Python script

**Python Script:**

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

def runSql(updateQry):
    bigqueryClient = bigquery.Client()
    sqlJob = bigqueryClient.query(updateQry)
    sqlJob.result()
    return 0

for i in range(20):
    fileName = "update_script_" + str(i+1) + ".sql"
    f = open(fileName, "r")
    updateQry = f.read()
    runSql(updateQry)
    print("Script {} Executed".format(fileName))
```

> **Note:** 
> `sqlJob.result()` will wait for the job to complete before proceeding to another job

Comment: If the solution is not useful for you, please let me know, so that I will delete my post !

Comment: Thank you, it is useful, but if possible I want to solve it within BigQuery, but this is only becuase how our current setup and etl process is done. I think you should leave it here, it might help others with the same problem. Thanks!